# Android, How to include specific library in project that is not a JAR file?

Tags: java, android, github, android-studio, libraries

I am trying to include [this](https://github.com/vdesmet93/holo-calendar) library in my android project, but there is no JAR file, or compile statement to put into my `build.gradle` file.

I've put their sample code in my project:

```
// Retrieve the CalendarView
MultiCalendarView multiMonth = (MultiCalendarView) findViewById(R.id.multi_calendar);
```

but I get a `Cannot resolve symbol 'MultiCalendarView'` error. I'm not sure which files from the [Github page](https://github.com/vdesmet93/holo-calendar) I need to include into my project, or even how to do it.

I am using the newest release of Android Studio.

**SOLUTION EDIT**

It was an issue importing the Calendar module into the project.

For Android Studio:

File -> Import Module...

And then follow the steps in Mike Laren's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holo-calendar doesn't release binaries on public repositories so you have to build it from source. To do so, pull the latest code to a submodule and include it in your Gradle build by adding this to your settings.gradle:

```
include 'Calendar'
```

The folder structure should be:

```
Root
  - YourApp
  - Calendar
  - settings.gradle
```

Finally, add a module dependency to the build.gradle of your app:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':Calendar')
}
```

And that should be it!

Comment: Got it, Thanks! It was an issue of properly importing the module and including it in my project.